# Safari iPhone doesn't show all images on page

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, safari

Device:  iPhone 7 Version iOS 11.4.1

Hello,
i have a problem with the display of some images.

First of all, this problem could only be reproduced on an iphone with the safari browser. The chrome browser works and all other devices with android works, too. Desktop also works. Mac's Safari and Chrome works, too.

It is only on iPhone and iPad with Safari.

Please have a look at this video: (You can jump to 0:40, there you can see the problem)
https://streamable.com/s/iyqtn/yncgdv

or have a look at this picture:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATyJM.png)

So, at some reason, some images are display and some images are not.
I guess it isn't a javascript bug, because i disabled JS and the problem is still there.

Do you know this problem? Is the problem something that the safari brwoser is dealing with?

Let me know what you think about it?